# Tcl problems refering to variables

Tags: variables, tcl

This question is kind of a follow-up from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734344/tcl-placing-a-value-of-a-variable-as-the-name-a-the-variable)…

I'm having some problems on top of the solution from the answers there. 
Ok, so the story is like this. I'm trying to write a script in colaborating with a electronic design viewer program. The problem I'm experiencing is using my variables correctly in the syntax of the electronic program.

So basically the meaning is this. I read some designs in, save the different paths in an array and then read them out one by one. During this reading one by one I open them in the program.

The original code for opening  the layout for the program is this:

```
set L1 [ layout create ]
$L1 create cell layout

$L1 create cell ONE
$L1 create cell TWO

set ONE [ layout create /users/jerre_111/public/imec_logo_zwart_512.gds -dt_expand -log LUN.log]
set ONE_top [$ONE topcell]
set TWO [ layout create /users/jerre_111/public/logo-rood.gds -dt_expand -log KTH.log]
set TWO_top [$TWO topcell]

$L1 import layout $ONE FALSE overwrite
$L1 import layout $TWO FALSE overwrite

$L1 create ref ONE $ONE_top      0       0 0 0 1
$L1 create ref TWO $TWO_top      0       0 0 0 1

$L1 create ref build ONE         0       0 0 0 1
$L1 create ref build TWO    207500       0 0 0 1
```

So, this is the original code. `ONE` and `TWO` are both two different layouts I open in the programm.

This is how it has to work in my script: I want to replace ONE and TWO dynamicly by the name of the file I open. So every time, I get the path out the array and then get the name out of the path. Then I want to use the name of the file instead of `ONE` and `TWO`. I'm trying it like this:

```
set L1 [ layout create ]
$L1 create cell build

foreach key [array names ::openedFiles] {
    set filename [file tail $::openedFiles($key)]
    set parts [split $filename .]
    set name [lindex $parts 0]

    $L1 create cell $name

    set $name[ layout create $::openedFiles($key) -dt_expand -log LUN.log]
    set cell_top [[set $name] topcell]

    $L1 import layout [set $name] FALSE overwrite

    $L1 create ref $name $cell_top     0       0 0 0 1

    $L1 create ref build $name         0       0 0 0 1
}
```

So every time I go through the loop I get one item out of the array. and then I dynamiclly give them the names. Butt I'm having some problems reffering to `$ONE` or `ONE`like in the original code... I'm trying to replace the `ONE` by the value of `$name`...

I hope you understand my problem and someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this code, you probably want to use an aliased variable.

```
# Compute the name of the variable to use as in your code...
# I assume that the name is what $name produces

upvar 0 $name ALIAS
```

After that, you can then use `ALIAS` or `$ALIAS` where the original sample used `ONE` or `$ONE`; they behave identically (until the end of the stack frame *or* until you redefine the alias with another `upvar 0` call).

```
$L1 create cell ALIAS

set ALIAS [layout create $::openedFiles($key) -dt_expand -log LUN.log]
set cell_top [$ALIAS topcell]

$L1 import layout $ALIAS FALSE overwrite

$L1 create ref ALIAS $cell_top     0       0 0 0 1
$L1 create ref build ALIAS         0       0 0 0 1
```

The only issue might be if the code retains a reference to the variable name. I'm guessing that this code doesn't, but some definitely does.

---

**Alternatively** use an array since things seem to expect a scalar. You could even use the array with an empty name:

```
$L1 create cell ($name)

set ($name) [layout create $::openedFiles($key) -dt_expand -log LUN.log]
set cell_top [$($name) topcell]

$L1 import layout $($name) FALSE overwrite

$L1 create ref ($name) $cell_top     0       0 0 0 1
$L1 create ref build ($name)         0       0 0 0 1
```

I don't really recommend using the empty name though; though it is going to be supported throughout the 8.* series of Tcl for sure, it's used in library packages (notably [stooop](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/stooop.html)), and we're not sure that we'll guarantee this as a supported feature in 9.0. An array with a one-letter name will be clearer IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first option you suggested didn't work for me. But the second one did! normally the name is never going to be empty so that is not going to be a problem I guess. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow, never thought about using an empty variable name for arrays. That is cool.